# vector product and scalar product equations

Tags: geometry, vectors, cross-product

Find $x$ given that $x \times a = b$ and $x \cdot c = d$ where $a \cdot c$ is not $0$.

Where $\times$ is the cross product and $\cdot$ is the dot product.

I have tried to manipulate this in more ways but everything led to a dead end, any starting point suggestions?

Comment: can you clarify what is given and what needs to be find? are $a,b$ constant vectors?

Comment: this is all that the question gives, I assume that a,b and c are constant vectors and we want to find the vector x that satisfies those connditions.

Comment: In what ways have you tried to "manipulate this"?  You claim "more ways" that you've tried this, but I see NO ways posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start with the vector triple product identity

$$ A \times (B \times C) = (A\cdot C ) B - (A\cdot B) C $$

This means that

$$ c \times (x \times a) + (c \cdot x) a = (c\cdot a) x $$

solving we get

$$ x = \frac{1}{a\cdot c} \left( c \times b + d a\right) $$

Comment: Really, @WillieWong?  This, from *you*?  A *full solution* to a PSQ??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $x=(x,y,z)$ and $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3),b=(b_1,b_2,b_3),c=(c_1,c_2,c_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ (known vectors),  and $d\in \mathbb{R}$ , so we have the system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
a_3y-a_2z=b_1\\
a_3y-a_1z=b_2\\
a_2x-a_1y=b_3\\
c_1x+c_2y+c_3z=d
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve it?